# Normal text in italicised title of apacite

Tags: bibtex, apacite

I am using BibTex in combination with apacite and looking for a way to add a note directly after a title in my reference list, in order to correctly refer to a quality standard number. I can't figure out how to get the following reference format:

Organization That Made the Standard. (year). *Title of the standard* (Standard No. 1234). Retrieved from http://xxxxx

Note how the Standard No. is directly after the title, between brackets and not italicised. I am currently using the following entry:

```
@misc{ieee3522016,
  author={{Institute of Electrical and Electronics Engineers}},
  title={{IEEE} Guide for General Principles of Reliability Analysis of Nuclear Power Generating Station Systems and Other Nuclear Facilities {(Std 352-2016)}},
  year={2017},
  url={https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/}
}
```

The output is:

Institute of Electrical and Electronics Engineers.  (2017). *IEEE guide for general principles of reliability analysis of nuclear power generating station systems and other nuclear facilities (Std 352-2016)*. Retrieved from https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/

But what I want is:

Institute of Electrical and Electronics Engineers.  (2017). *IEEE guide for general principles of reliability analysis of nuclear power generating station systems and other nuclear facilities* (Std 352-2016). Retrieved from https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/

Comment: Uhm, as long as that string is in the entry "title" I don't think there is an easy way to change the output.

Comment: A quick and dirty trick would be to say `\textup{(Std 352-2016)}` instead of `{(Std 352-2016)}` (I haven't checked for lack of an MWE, but I expect it should work). But maybe there is a more appropriate entry type for things like this.